# ActionMailer acting different on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have a action mailer method as something like this:

```
def mail
 @receiver = User.where(status: 2).pluck(:email)
 mail(bcc:@receiver, to: "username@gmail.com")
end
```

**application.yml** looks like this:

```
SMTP_ADDRESS: 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT: 587
SMTP_HOST: 'localhost:3000'
SMTP_DOMAIN: 'localhost:3000'
SMTP_USERNAME: 'user@gmail.com'
SMTP_PASSWORD: 'xxxxx'
SUPER_ADMIN_EMAIL: 'super_admin@mailinator.com'
```

**developmet.rb** looks like this:

```
config.action_mailer.asset_host = ENV["SMTP_HOST"]
  # config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    #Enter the smtp provider here ex: smtp.mandrillapp.com
    address: ENV["SMTP_ADDRESS"],
    port: ENV['SMTP_PORT'].to_i,
    #Enter the smtp domain here ex: vendaxo.com
    domain: ENV["SMTP_DOMAIN"],
    #Enter the user name for smtp provider here
    user_name: ENV["SMTP_USERNAME"],
    #Enter the password for smtp provider here
    password: ENV["SMTP_PASSWORD"],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
```

Where receivers are kept in BCC but "username@gmail.com" will be able to see the BCCd receivers. This is working fine when I send the mails from my local host. When receivers are sent emails, all of them are in BCC and one 'username@gmail.com' is able to see all the receivers.

But when I do the same thing on production server with similar **application.yml** configuration changing the host and port  the *username@gmail.com* is NOT GETTING the emails of BCCd receivers.

Comment: Might be helpful https://www.sitepoint.com/deliver-the-mail-with-amazon-ses-and-rails/

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are running your production server on AWS EC2 (may be other providers too), every time you do some changes to your **application.yml** or any other shared file, you need to restart the app server in order to apply the changed configurations . In my case I had to restart the PUMA, and the one default email started to get BCCd email ids.